# How is プレゼントしてくれた different from プレゼントした?

Tags: grammar

あなたがプレゼントしてくれたカバン、今でも大切にしているよ。

あなたがプレゼントしたカバン、今でも大切にしているよ。

I can't understand why してくれた is the right form to say *the bag you gave me as a present* in the past tense.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) あなたがプレゼント**してくれ**たカバン、今{いま}でも大切{たいせつ}にしているよ。
>
> 2) あなたがプレゼント**した**カバン、今でも大切にしているよ。

Both sentences are grammatical, but they mean ***completely*** different things.  I am sure many other users here will thank you for asking this question because this is an extremely common mistake among Japanese-learners.

Present-**giver**:

1) the listener （あなた）

2) the listener （あなた）

Present-**receiver**:

1) the speaker (unmentioned) -- "me"

2) **a third person** (unmentioned) -- "Bob", "Mr. Takahashi", etc.

「くれる」 expresses an action being performed for (the benefit of) the ***speaker*** and not for anyone else.  The English equivalent of this would be "doing something for/to me".

Thus, the two sentences mean:

> 1) I still treasure the bag that you gave me as a present.
>
> 2) (Someone) still treasures the bag that you gave (him/her) as a present.

Strictly speaking, however, it would be more natural to say 2) as:

> あなたがプレゼント**してあげた**カバン、今でも大切にしているよ。

Unlike 「くれる」, 「あげる」 expresses an action being performed for a ***person other than the speaker***.

Comment: thanks.  So, either「くれる」or「あげる」should always be attached to a verb, if that verb is an action that was done for someone's sake? What I mean is, for example is this: 「私の兄は彼の車を運転させた。」 less correct than this: 「私の兄は私に彼の車を運転させてくれた。」?

Comment: @ericfromabeno It depends. You don't use くれる when you don't mean your position to thank the giver. Btw you call your family 彼?